# How to make a spaceship do U turn?

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is my code i really tried everything that i see in internet but i didnt find good solution for this problem .
i can rotate my spaceship , i can make that U turn . but i cant do those ,at the same time.

[image: Editor Image]

```cs
void Movements() 
{ 
    float deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;
    bool isLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
    bool isRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D); 
    bool isTurningLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);                                   
    bool isTurningRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
    
    if (isTurningLeft) 
    { 
        newRotation = new Quaternion(transform.localRotation.x, transform.localRotation.y,  transform.localRotation.z, transform.localRotation.w);
        this.newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, -50, 15);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime); 
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime; 
        print("2"); 
    } 

    if (isTurningRight && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    { 
        newRotation = new Quaternion(transform.localRotation.x, transform.localRotation.y, transform.localRotation.z, transform.localRotation.w);
        this. newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 50, -15);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime); 
        transform.position += transform.forward  * Time.deltaTime; 
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !isTurningRight && !isTurningLeft)
    { 
        TargetObject =  Quaternion.identity; 
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 20 * deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: btw you know that instead of `newRotation = new Quaternion(transform.localRotation.x, transform.localRotation.y,  transform.localRotation.z, transform.localRotation.w);` you could just write `newRotation = transform.localRotation`? ;) Besides that ... I have a bit trouble to understand what exactly your issue is ... could you describe a bit more in detail what you want vs what happens instead?

Comment: i want to rotate like a real spaceship . when you press W+A / D , rotate spaceship + rotate the direction of the spaceship